# Can’t push to docker hub (authentication required)

Tags: docker, windows-10, push, docker-registry

I've just installed Docker on Windows 10 few days ago. Seems I am able to login to my Docker Hub repo (by entering winpty docker login in my git-bash on windows). **It says "Login succeded"**. But after I try to push (docker push myrepo/myproject:sometag) it says finally "authentication required". **I've googled and researched yesterday whole of the day about this (also on stackoverflow), but no help.** Various advices that looked promising just did not help in my occasion. I understand problem is probably somewhere in Users/MyName/.docker/config.json. I've noticed that file is not the same as in boot2docker (version for windows 7). And in Windows 7 (which I use at my home) push works perfect. I must also say that **I am running docker on Windows 10 behind corporate proxy**. And proxy is set as it should be. I can even run maven commands behind proxy when doing docker build. It's doing perfect. But I just can't make push to docker hub repo.
Can you give me advice what to do? I've run out of options. Login works, but not push. This is how my Users/MyName/.docker/**config.json** looks like:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "xxxx",
            "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me about auth variable? I think maybe problem is in it. I would like to generate it by myself if there maybe where problem lies. As I've read, it is username:pass base64 hash. But I'm not sure if that is correct. Or some more params are missing. As I said, config.json is a lot different in boot2docker version.I'm stuck on this and just can't go further.

My Docker version is 1.12.5. Please help!

Here is example what is happening: 
[image]

Comment: There don't seem to have any pb with your config. Though, you made the login from the git-bash command. Could you try login from boot2docker instead (if it's possible) ? (I don't really know the usage of docker on windows, but as you say it doesn't look like the one from boot2docker on windows 7).

Comment: I don't have boot2docker on win10.. I only have this version. i think solution is not to install 2 versions of docker.. right?

Comment: Wild guess: is `winpty` putting the result of your docker login someplace unexpected? If you delete the contents of the the config.json auths section and docker login, is config.json updated?

Answer (score -3):

Check status.docker.com

they are in the middle of the incident

Comment: Says "Docker Hub Web" that is currently in Degraded performance. So you say it will eventualy work.. ?

Comment: today there is not any incident, but I can't connect. What then is the problem?

Comment: Same problem, i can push a test repo.